generate multiple random words from array
I got this code off here.  It selects one of the names at random.  All I need is to select more than one name but not repeat any


var textArray = [
  "Hello I'm Fred1",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy1",
  "Hello I'm Terry1",
  "Hello I'm Fred2",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy2",
  "Hello I'm Terry2",
  "Hello I'm Fred3",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy3",
  "Hello I'm Terry3"
];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length); 
document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = textArray[randomNumber];
  <p id="randomNumber"> </p>



I can't figure it out

for starters, there are no elements with the id randomNumber in the code you provided. Perhaps you meant to use document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML ?

What do you mean, "select more than one name but not repeat any"? Do you mean you want to randomly pick a "Hello I'm [name]" and switch it to it until you run out of names?

The code now works I copied it wrong.  I want to randomly pick more than one line from the array, this code only picks one

@TomWebb how many lines do you need?

I need 3 lines.

You are attempting a partial Fisher-Yates shuffle.  Rethink the problem as randomly shuffling the order of the items in the list, and then you can just select items in order.

Just randomly splice from the array's shallow copy:


var textArray = [
  "Hello I'm Fred1",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy1",
  "Hello I'm Terry1",
  "Hello I'm Fred2",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy2",
  "Hello I'm Terry2",
  "Hello I'm Fred3",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy3",
  "Hello I'm Terry3"
];


const copy = textArray.slice();
const result = Array.from({length:5}, () => copy.splice(Math.random() * copy.length | 0, 1)[0]);

document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = result.join('<br/>')
<p id="demo"></p>




I don't like to pick a favorite but ok @Alexander

One way to do it:
Generate three random indices for selecting lines.
Select the lines at the random indices
Join the selected lines into a single string with line breaks


var textArray = [
  "Hello I'm Fred1",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy1",
  "Hello I'm Terry1",
  "Hello I'm Fred2",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy2",
  "Hello I'm Terry2",
  "Hello I'm Fred3",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy3",
  "Hello I'm Terry3"
];

var randomIndices = [];
while (randomIndices.length < 3) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length);
  if (!randomIndices.includes(randomIndex)) {
    randomIndices.push(randomIndex);
  }
}

var selectedLines = randomIndices.map(index => textArray[index]);
var output = selectedLines.join("<br>");

document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = output;
<p id="randomNumber"></p>




ugh, You unaccepted my answer, could I at least get a thumbs up?
